# Careers profile editing sometimes fails with a blank page and sudden logout

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, jobs, cv

I'm working on updating my Careers CV, and it has now twice today happened to me that after editing a section (both times this took quite some time, which may be a related fact) and clicking "save", all I received was a blank page. When returning to careers, I was no longer logged in, and my submission had not been saved.

At other times, submission worked just fine.

I wasn't running Fiddler so far, but have started it now, so in case it happens a third time I may be able to give some additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was a problem affecting only us devs on careers. The cobblers don't even have shoes around here.

**UPDATE**

Turns out there was another issue that was causing the same behavior for all users. The request to careers that populates the Job ads in the sidebar of StackOverflow was attempting to rotate user cookies. We rotated the cookie in the database, but the browser never got the update because the request was cross domain.

Essentially browsing around stack overflow for a little while would log you out of careers. Whoopsie Doodle!

This has been fixed now.

If you see any more weird logouts please let us know.

Comment: _affecting only devs_ hmm `if (debug) { breakThePage(); logout(); }` stuff like that? :)

Comment: @gnat: Basically.