# Add a one-click "show next picture" to the company page gallery

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

When I look at the photo gallery on a Careers company page (like [our own](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange#gallery)), I'd usually like to look at *all* the pictures. However the gallery UI is optimized for the case that you're looking for a specific picture (scan thumbnails, click "next" arrow, scan thumbnails, etc. until you've found the correct thumbnail, click that thumbnail).

But when you want to flip through all the pictures (which, I assume, is 1. a much more common use case, and 2. probably also the use case that should be *encouraged*), you have to click thumbnail after thumbnail, and every seven pictures click the "next page" arrow, and back to clicking thumbnails.

Can we have a way to browse the pictures one-by-one easily?

Comment: Just curious, did you bring it up internally before posting here (knowing it will be done), or just asked as an ordinary user of Careers? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just posted it here. That's what we usually do in such a case. Unless there's a good reason like security etc., why shouldn't we use the same channels as everyone else? Not a first time either, by the way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157024/careers-is-missing-the-good-parts http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157009/careers-profile-editing-sometimes-fails-with-a-blank-page-and-sudden-logout

Comment: Thanks, as I said was just curious. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've now made it so you can click or tap the picture to move to the next one.

Comment: Facebook style! ;)

Comment: Thanks Alex! Can I suggest a `cursor:pointer` to make it a bit more obvious? Works great though.

Comment: @balpha Good idea - done!